# Sources (other than Serre) for learning the basic GAGA type theorems?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, complex-geometry

I'm just beginning my second year as a graduate student. I know a bit of complex geometry and a bit of algebraic geometry. The lack of rigor in my understanding of the connection of the two is growing a bit frustrating, so I'd like to learn about analytification and so on. I'm sure Serre is good, but I suspect I'd appreciate a more recent exposition (preferably in English).

Comment: There is a translation of GAGA. Math never becomes out of date, and it wasn't written that long ago in the grand scheme of things, so it may be worth a shot.

Comment: For a readable introduction by a master, check out Griffiths and Adams, *Algebraic and Analytic Geometry* (Princeton yellow).

Answer (score 5):

There is the book [Algebraic and Analytic Geometry](https://www.amazon.de/Algebraic-Analytic-Geometry-Mathematical-Society/dp/0521709830) by Neeman which focuses on GAGA and is very detailed. It starts with basics in manifold and scheme theory, continues with analytification and ends with GAGA theorems of varying/increasing generality as far as I remember. I guess this might be the reference that you were searching for.

Comment: Read the introduction.. if you think it is not well written, leave it.. I bet you will not leave it :D I read introduction just after seeing this answer.. this book is a masterpiece for advanced undergraduate students...